# How can I make this pop up automatic?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

My code is

```js
function PopUp() {
  document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#ac-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .6);
  z-index: 1001;
}

#popup {
  width: 555px;
  height: 375px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  left: 375px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ac-wrapper">
  <div id="popup">
    <center>
      <h2>Popup Content Here</h2> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="PopUp()" />
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I force popup to open automatically 5 seconds after the page opens?

Comment: What does it mean `automatic`?

Comment: Please clarify your question with more details

Comment: To clarify, I want the popup to open 5 seconds after the page opens

Comment: sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, don't post code in comments, post it in the original question.

Secondly, you can execute a function (i.e. 'automatic' as in no user input required), by simply invoking it, `PopUp()`.

Thirdly, to add a delay, there's the `setTimeout(func, delay)` function.

Fourthly, adhere to common styling guidelines. E.g.,

- single quotes `'` instead of `"` when possible in JS;
- lowercase function names `popUp`;
- space before braces in func definitions;
- don't adjust style directly in JS, instead toggle a class.

```
  function popUp() {
    document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = 'none';
    // document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').classList.toggle('hidden');
  }
  setTimeout(popUp, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by `Javascript` or by `CSS` with a bit of JS to add a class on click event on the close popup.

```
//JS

setTimeout(function(){ 
  document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = 'block';
}, 5000);
```

```
//CSS
div {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  animation-name: showPopup;
  animation-delay: 5s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  from {
   opacity: 0;
   pointer-events: none;
  }
  to {
   opacity: 1;
   pointer-events: auto;
  }
}

div.hidden {
  display: none;
  pointer-events: none; // just to be sure
}
```